# Link to anchor but wait for the page to load

Tags: html, anchor, loading

I want to link to an external anchor in a page but above the anchor thre is a gallery that reload and change the height and the position so if I click on the anchor is sends me to the wrong position. what can i do?

Comment: Please elaborate the issue with the code

Comment: i dont use jquery or anything. the link to the anchor is simple link. "www.example.com/page#anchor". the gallery is a bunch of images with different heights.